# How to set variables to supervisor and gunicorn config from os variables?

Tags: django, gunicorn, supervisord, django-deployment

Hi i have set up some variables to Linux(have added them  to `~/.bashrc`).

I know that it is possible to set variables to supervisor `environment= KEY=value` and to gunicorn i may simple add in config `export KEY1='value'`

Is any way to add variables only to `~/.bashrc` and take them to all configs?

Thx for any help.

Comment: If you are populating them with python code, you can always find them with `import os; os.environ`

Comment: i think that it isn't python code it is config syntax

Answer (score 0):

If supervisor/gunicorn is run as the same user it should already be set and available, otherwise you have to list them manually. Or use `python-decouple` and an `.env` file which feels much more right than relying on how your SSH session personally prefers its bash.